# Bluetooth - Try connecting your device again

Tags: bluetooth

I've had some Bluetooth headphones for a while, but today they disconnected randomly and I can't connect them again.  The error message is "Try connecting your device again"; which I do, and then just loop back to the error message.

I've tried rebooting both the computer and headphones, and I can't seem to find anything on Microsoft's help about this error.

[image]

So what does this error mean, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Try the usual remove and re-pair.

Comment: Tried it. Goes back to Try connecting this device again. What worked for now is I left them be for like an hour and then tried again and that worked. What is annoying as hell is that there is no error code or anything that can make me debug that error. It's just 'Well fuck you, it doesn't work'

Comment: Having written some WinRT code recently, I can tell you that this error translates to `OperationAlreadyInProgress`

Comment: For me it was related to the bluetooth services, the bluetooth support service in particular. 

Make sure it's running (obviously). When it didn't run I could not discover any bluetooth devices.

To get rid of the "Try Connecting Your Device Again" error, I had to set "Log On" (a tab under properties) to "LOCAL SERVICE".

You can find it under browse -> advanced -> find now -> local service. 

Credits to this guide for pointing me in the right direction (also with pictures)

https://appuals.com/fix-bluetooth-couldnt-connect-on-windows-10/

Answer (score 0):

I tried removing the device from the list,
then I turned off the bluetooth on the device and 
clicked it on the "add new device" list. 
Then I waited a bit for the computer to load and
turned the device on. The problem is they both have bluetooth on at the same time.
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen on Windows 11. Just restart the computer and the problem might be solved.